# Magento indexer on save not working

Tags: magento

I have created one additional indexer in my magento shop
where it work fine while execution command

```
php indexer.php reindexall

php indexer.php --reindex myindex
```

i have also set myindex on "update on save" mode

it did not work

when i track the code first we have to register event  by execution function `_registerEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)`
which is function of abstract class Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract

after registering event

`_processEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)` should be executed. where it executed while execution indexer from command line but it doesn’t execute "on update" and my indexer say update required.